# Which pair of ternary quadratic forms in Bhargava's theory parameterize the ring of integers of the quartic number field of discriminant $225$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The binary quartic form $\mathcal{V} = (a, b, c, d, e)$ has the same discriminant $D$ as the binary cubic form 
\begin{equation}\label{resolvform}
\mathcal{C} = \left( 1, - c, b d - 4 a e, 4 a c e - a d^2 - b^2 e \right) . 
\end{equation}
The Hessian $\mathcal{Q}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and the Jacobian $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ have $\mathcal{Q}(1, 0) = i$ and $\mathcal{F}(1, 0) = - j$. Since $\mathcal{C}(1, 0) = 1$, the identity $j^2 + 27 D = 4 i^3$ is a consequence of Cayley's syzygy $\mathcal{F}^2 + 27 D \mathcal{C}^2 = 4 \mathcal{Q}^3$. The forms $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ parameterize rings. The matrices 
\begin{equation*}
M_4 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 u & -a e z & -e (a y+b z) & -e (a x+b y+c z) \\
 x & u-b x-c y-d z & -c x-d y-e z & -d x-e y \\
 y & a x & u-c y-d z & -d y-e z \\
 z & a y & a x+b y & u-d z \\
\end{array}
\right) ,
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{equation*}
M_3 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 U & -k Y & c k Y-k X \\
 X & U+c X-(b d-4 a e) Y & -(b d-4 a e) X-k Y \\
 Y & X & U-(b d-4 a e) Y \\
\end{array}
\right) ,
\end{equation*}
where $k =  4 a c e - a d^2 - b^2 e$, take care of multiplication in each of these rings via matrix multiplication; the $\alpha = u + x \rho_1 + y \rho_2 + z \rho_3$ can be added and multiplied using matrices. Multiplication tables can be recovered from $M_4$ and $M_3$.

[Wood](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5501) showed that binary quartic forms parameterize rings with monogenic cubic resolvent rings. 
\begin{align*}
A & = \frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right) , & B & = \frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 e & 0 & d \\
 0 & 2 a & b \\
 d & b & 2 c \\
\end{array}
\right) ,
\end{align*}
corresponds to the pair of ternary quadratic forms 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Q}_1 & = x y - z^2 , & \mathcal{Q}_2 & = e x^2 + a y^2 + b y z + d x z + c z^2 .
\end{align*} 
The pair of matrices $(A, B)$ was then mapped to the binary cubic form 
\begin{equation*}
4 \det \left( A x + B y \right) = \mathcal{C} . 
\end{equation*}
If I understood correctly, in this way Wood showed that $\mathcal{Q}_1 $ and $\mathcal{Q}_2$ parameterize the same quartic ring that $\mathcal{V}$ does.

Not all quartic rings come from binary quartic forms. For [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935205/) $y^2 = 4 x^3 - 6075$ has no integral points so the ring of integers of the quartic field of discriminant $225$ is not parameterized by a binary quartic form.

Now let $K = \mathbb{Q} (\zeta )$ be a quartic field of discriminant $\Delta $, where $\zeta $ is a root of $\mathcal{V}(x, 1)$. The discriminant $D$ of $\mathcal{V}$ satisfies $D = \Delta a_0^2 $, where $a_0$ is the index of $\mathbb{Z} [\zeta ]$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. If $a_0^2$ divides $a$ and $a_0$ divides $b$, then the matrix 
\begin{equation*}
B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{3 b^2-8 a c}{a_0^2} & \frac{2 (b c-6 a d)}{a_0} & \frac{b d-16 a e}{a_0} \\
 \frac{2 (b c-6 a d)}{a_0} & 4 c^2-8 b d-16 a e & 2 c d-12 b e \\
 \frac{b d-16 a e}{a_0} & 2 c d-12 b e & 3 d^2-8 c e \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{equation*}
is an integral matrix of determinant $16 \Delta $, and hence may be a candidate for one of a pair of matrices $(A, B)$ parameterizing the ring of integers of the quartic number field of discriminant $225$, where $a_0 = 2$ and $(a,b,c,d,e) = (4, -6, 5, -3, 1)$ .

Which pair of ternary quadratic forms in [Bhargava's](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2004/159-3/p08) theory parameterize the ring of integers of the quartic number field of discriminant $225$?